# How can I fix the 07002 too few parameters in this program?

Tags: python, sql, ms-access, pyodbc

Trying to write a simple program to parse Excel sheets then store the data in a Access database.

I'm not entirely sure what the issue is, I've tried renaming parameters, double checking spelling, etc.

```
cursor.execute('select * from MSDB')
cursor.execute('''
    INSERT INTO MSDB ([SalesOrder], [SiteNumber], [SiteName], [Customer], [ShipDate])
    VALUES(SO, SNM, Custom, SD, SN)
              ''')
conn.commit()

else:
    continue
```

This gives me the error:

> pyodbc.Error: ('07002', '[07002] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]
>  Too few parameters. Expected 5. (-3010) (SQLExecDirectW)')

Comment: You'll need to concatenate the SQL string to evaluate the variables `SO`, `SNM` etc., they won't be evaluated by the SQL engine; or better yet, parameterise the query to avoid SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
sql = "INSERT INTO MSDB ([SalesOrder], [SiteNumber], [SiteName], [Customer],ShipDate])
VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)"
cursor.execute(sql,(SO, SNM, Custom, SD, SN))
```

it will help you

Comment: I get invalid syntax on cursur.execute(sql,(SO, SNM, Custom, SD, SN)) with that.

sql = ("INSERT INTO MSDB ([SalesOrder], [SiteNumber], [SiteName], [Customer],ShipDate])) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)"
cursor.execute(sql,(SO, SNM, Custom, SD, SN))

Comment: can you please tell me the type of data that you are passing into the query.i.e. SO,SNM,Custom,SD,SN are they variables or a list or something else

Comment: They are simply variables, im trying to pull data from excel, just simple text or numbers then pass them through to an access database.
        SalesO = worksheet['T5']
        SiteNum = worksheet['F5']
        SiteN = worksheet['F4']
        Cust = worksheet ['F3']
        ShipD = worksheet['T3']

Comment: I updated some other parts of my code, and after trying your suggestion again I end up with this error. pyodbc.Error: ('HYC00', '[HYC00] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]Optional feature not implemented  (106) (SQLBindParameter)
        cursor.execute('select * from MSDB')
        sql = "INSERT INTO MSDB (SalesOrder, SiteNumber, SiteName, Customer, ShipDate) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)"
        cursor.execute(sql,(SalesO.value, SiteNum.value, SiteN.value, Cust.value, ShipD.value))
        conn.commit()

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20240130/optional-feature-not-implemented-106-sqlbindparameter-error-with-pyodbc                                                                                            please go through this link for more details about your error

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work, for whatever reason I needed to convert ints to floats.
Here was the final bit of code that worked for me.

```
params = (SalesO.value, SiteNum.value, SiteN.value, Cust.value, ShipD.value)
    params = [float(x) if type(x) is int else x for x in params] #Convert all int items to floats
    conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\Users\llippincott\Desktop\MS DB_be.accdb;')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('select * from MSDB')
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO MSDB (SalesOrder, SiteNumber, SiteName, Customer, ShipDate) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)", (params))
    conn.commit()
```